# Query DELETE demorando muito para ser carregado

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tendo um problema com uma query, ela tem a função de excluir alguns registros duplicados existentes em uma tabela.

Segue:

```
DELETE t1 
FROM bid_account t1 
    INNER JOIN bid_account t2 
WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND 
    t1.bidding_price = t2.bidding_price AND 
    t1.auction_id = '" . $obj->auction_id . "' AND 
    t1.bidding_type = 's' AND 
    t1.bid_flag = 'd' AND 
    DATE(t1.bidpack_buy_date) >= DATE(NOW())
```

O problema é que ao executar ela, demora muito para concluir e não resolve nada, parece não funcionar.

Eu fiz um select com essas mesmas condições, e algo absurdo aconteceu, ele repetiu vários registros, que não existem, por ex para o leilão com ID 15 tem 100 registros, ao consultar usando essas condições ele retorna mais de 80 mil registros.

Como posso fazer essa query funcionar corretamente?

Comment: Parece haver um **erro de lógica** no seu `SQL`. Se na consulta retorna mais de 80.000 registros é porque seus relacionamentos estão incorretos. Ou talvez o resultado seja esse mesmo.  
De qualquer forma, eu evitaria fazer esse `JOIN` que vc fez.... talvez seja melhor fazer um `Exists`, para evitar essas duplicidades.

Comment: tambem acho que você precisa melhorar seu sql.. tem muita clausula alem do join. Se no select já retorna muitos registros, vai demorar mesmo no delete. Tente simplificar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Antes de responder, vamos colocar alguns pontos nos *is*:

> Eu fiz um select com essas mesmas condições, e algo absurdo aconteceu, ele repetiu vários registros, que não existem, por ex para o leilão com ID 15 tem 100 registros, ao consultar usando essas condições ele retorna mais de 80 mil registros.

Nada de absurdo aconteceu. Esse resultado é um produto cartesiano que foi provocado pelo fato de você ter declarado um `JOIN` da tabela `bid_account` com ela mesmo sem qualquer restrição. Então, supondo que você tivesse 10 registros nela. O resultado seria 10 * 10 = 100 registros no resultado inicial. Na sequencia é que seriam aplicadas as restrições que você declarou no `WHERE`, o que poderia diminuir esse número (mas não muito).

> Ao executar ela, demora muito para concluir e não resolve nada, parece não funcionar.

Demora! E para cada novo registro que for inserido nela, a demora aumenta exponencialmente. Isso certamente é pelo mesmo motivo do ponto acima.

### Versão TLDR;

Se eu entendi corretamente, você quer eliminar registros que estão completamente repetidos em `bid_account` e manter somente o que tem o menor id. Nesse caso, sua consulta deveria ser assim*:

```
DELETE t1 
FROM bid_account t1 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
               FROM bid_account t2 
               WHERE t2.bidding_price = t1.bidding_price AND
                    t2.auction_id = t1.auction_id AND
                    t2.bidding_type  = t1.bidding_type AND 
                    t2.bid_flag = t1.bid_flag AND 
                    DATE(t2.bidpack_buy_date) = DATE(t1.bidpack_buy_date) AND
                    t2.id < t1.id) AND
    t1.auction_id = '" . $obj->auction_id . "' AND 
    t1.bidding_type = 's' AND 
    t1.bid_flag = 'd' AND 
    DATE(t1.bidpack_buy_date) >= DATE(NOW())
```

** Nota: Você deverá avaliar se as regras que definem a sua "duplicidade" são essas mesmo que eu declarei no subselect. É ali que você deve identificá-las. No `WHERE` você estabelece seus critérios para exclusão (exceto o que identifica a duplicidade). Assim sua query fica mais limpa e mais fácil de fazer ajustes como mudar os critérios*

### Um pouco mais sobre o que aconteceu

Na sua query, com o que foi declarado como restrições no `where` e supondo que a tabela tenha o conteúdo abaixo, teríamos o seguinte:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | bidding_price |        auction_id        | bidding_type | bid_flag | bidpack_buy_date |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |           2.0 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | s            | d        |    05/05/2018    | // Seria eliminado de t1 porque o id não é maior do que nenhum de t2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2 |           2.0 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | s            | d        |    13/08/2018    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3 |           2.0 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | s            | d        |    17/10/2019    | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  4 |           1.2 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | s            | a        |    22/02/2019    | // Seria eliminado de t1 pelo flag 'a'
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  5 |           1.2 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | t            | d        |    30/09/2018    | // Seria eliminado de t1 pelo tipo 't'
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  6 |           1.2 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | s            | d        |    01/04/2017    | // Seria eliminado de t1 pela data menor que hoje
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Então, sobraram 2 registros de `t1` e todos os de `t2` pois pelo menos um registro de `t2` tem `id` menor do que cada um `id` de `t1` e possui `bidding_price` equivalente também.
Sabendo que o processamento já seria relativamente lento pelo produto cartesiano, se fizessemos um `Select t1.* ...` teríamos como resultado final o seguinte (2 * 6 = 12):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | bidding_price |        auction_id        | bidding_type | bid_flag | bidpack_buy_date |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2 |           2.0 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | s            | d        |    13/08/2018    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3 |           2.0 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | s            | d        |    17/10/2019    | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2 |           2.0 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | s            | d        |    13/08/2018    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3 |           2.0 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | s            | d        |    17/10/2019    | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2 |           2.0 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | s            | d        |    13/08/2018    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3 |           2.0 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | s            | d        |    17/10/2019    | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2 |           2.0 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | s            | d        |    13/08/2018    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3 |           2.0 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | s            | d        |    17/10/2019    | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2 |           2.0 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | s            | d        |    13/08/2018    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3 |           2.0 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | s            | d        |    17/10/2019    | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2 |           2.0 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | s            | d        |    13/08/2018    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3 |           2.0 | " . $obj->auction_id . " | s            | d        |    17/10/2019    | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Espero que isso ajude.

Comment: Óptima explicação. espero que ajude o OP.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza [Quais são as abreviações/gírias mais comuns usadas no Stack Overflow em Português?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6311/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-abrevia%C3%A7%C3%B5es-g%C3%ADrias-mais-comuns-usadas-no-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AA/6312#6312) :D

Answer (score 1):

A melhor solução que encontro é estabeleceres um limite para apagar.
Faz o delete na mesma acrescentando, por exemplo, LIMIT 10000 no final da query. Apaga os registos na mesma mas por parcelas.

Um ciclo ou uma rotina para ir executando essa query e penso que o problema fica resolvido.